# PNG image is not loading properly in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using the below code to view the following image.

[image: This]

(If you cannot see the image, right click the above space and save image..)
The image is 32 bit.
OpenCV shows white image. It is a white arrow image, with alpha value around it.

```
Mat img = imread("FordwardIcon.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
cout << img.depth() << "\t" << img.channels() << endl;
imshow("img", img);
waitKey(0);
```

Kindly let me know how to correctly load the image

Comment: I guess the problem is, that the image is 2 channeled (1 grayscale and 1 alpha channel). Creating  RGBA image in gimp and reading in opencv worked fine for me. Afaik OpenCV (or the underlying codec?!?) is limited in WRITING png files (3 channels only), so maybe reading is limited too in some way.

Comment: it looks like imread doesnt support 2 channel images, as Micka suggests.

Comment: @Canberk Baci Okay..do u have inputs on how to load the attached image in OpenCV

Comment: opencv is good at processing images, not reading them. you need a proper acquisition toolbox like http://libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html. you can create two channel Mat, use windows SDK or libpng to read the image into an array; and push the data to Mat by hand.

Answer (score 3):

no fear, your image loaded correctly.

the problem is more that you expected imshow() to honour the alpha channel ( it does not ) .

Comment: but opencv says, channels = 1 and bitDepth = 8 The pixel values are all nearly 255 when I print it by cout<<img ... but original image is 32bit(view details by windows properties).

Comment: oh, all i could judge so far, was your code ( which seems correct ). why not edit & append your image, so people can try it ?

Comment: Image is already attached between the first line and second line(but not visible). right click and save the image and test it. it is a white image with alpha channel

Comment: ooh, ok . i get the same weird values. puzzled.

Answer (score 3):

At present, Opencv (3.0) does not seem to be able to load png images with transparency (aka "alpha channel"). To load these kind of images with `cv::imread()`, you need to remove the transparency channel first, and replace it with some color.

This can be done easily with Linux using the Imagemagick tools. For example:

```
convert input.png -background '#00ff00' -flatten result.png
```

You can check if an image has it (or not) with the `file` tool. On the image you provide:

```
>$ file input.png
```

gives:

```
input.png: PNG image data, 52 x 32, 8-bit gray+alpha, non-interlaced
```

while

```
>$ file result.png
```

gives

```
result.png: PNG image data, 52 x 32, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Comment: the ``CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED`` does load png with alpha channel. As the other answer pointed out, it is imshow which causes the problem